# Check if there is overlap between elements of a list

Tags: r, set, unique

I have a list of integers and I want to check if the elements are all unique ones.

```
set.seed(2)
x <- list(a=sample(10,3),b=sample(10,5),c=sample(10,7))
x
# $a
# [1] 2 7 5
# $b
# [1] 2 9 8 1 6
# $c
# [1]  5 10  9  2  8  1  7
```

For this example, all of the following situations fails the check: 1) 2 appears in all entries, 2) 5 appears in `$a` and `$c`, 3) 8 appears in `$b` and `$c`, 4) 1 appears in `$b` and `$c`, etc.

```
y <- list(a=c(1,3,5),b=c(7,4),c=c(6,10))
```

There is no overlapping between elements of `y`, so it passes the check.

The expected output should be just True/False indicating whether the list passes the check.

Comment: What is the expected output?  Do you want just a TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: Yes, just a boolean tells whether the list passes the check.

Comment: As akrun asked in a comment on my answer, what is the expected behavior if `y$b` is `c(4, 4)`? Should `y` then pass the test (no duplicates between elements of `y`) or fail the test (4 appears twice in `y`)?

Comment: @nicola The question is not clear to me when I commented.  Now, also it is not clear.  I think the OP wanted to check all the combinations of list elements for any intersects. I am not sure.

Comment: @akrun Sorry, you are right, I was just wandering. I'm removing mine also. Your comments very often are as valuable as answers, so I took it too seriously :) Sorry again if I looked rude.

Comment: @nicola You are right about the Reduce.  I had my doubts about that code, but then I forgot to delete that comment after josilber answered.  It's not about being rude or anyting.  I just thought we should spend our valuable time on something that is useful.  BTW, I always find your comments very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to a vector with `unlist` and then check if any elements are duplicated in the vector with `any` and `duplicated`.

```
!any(duplicated(unlist(x)))
# [1] FALSE
!any(duplicated(unlist(y)))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: @akrun Do you mean `y$b[1] <- 4`? If so we should ask Francis to indicate what should be done in that case.

Comment: My understanding is that suppose all the duplicates are in a single list element, and there are only unique elements in other elements, wouldn't `duplicated` still returns `TRUE`

Comment: @akrun Understood -- I've asked Francis for clarification in a comment on the main question. If your understanding is correct that your solution with `Reduce` and `%in%` is great; alternately I could rescue mine by replacing `x` and `y` with `lapply(x, unique)` and `lapply(y, unique)`, respectively.

Comment: @josilber I think if the OP needed any overlaps, using `combn` might be an option.  But, I don't know what is the expected output.

Comment: @akrun me neither -- waiting for OP to respond to my comment on the question.